# How to match ets:match against a record in Erlang?

Tags: erlang, tuples, record, ets

I have heard that specifying records through tuples in the code is a bad practice: I should always use record fields (`#record_name{record_field = something}`) instead of plain tuples `{record_name, value1, value2, something}`.

But how do I match the record against an ETS table? If I have a table with records, I can only match with the following:

```
ets:match(Table, {$1,$2,$3,something}
```

It is obvious that once I add some new fields to the record definition this pattern match will stop working.

Instead, I would like to use something like this:

```
ets:match(Table, #record_name{record_field=something})
```

Unfortunately, it returns an empty list.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The cause of your problem is what the unspecified fields are set to when you do a `#record_name{record_field=something}`. This is the syntax for *creating* a record, here you are creating a record/tuple which ETS will interpret as a pattern. When you create a record then all the unspecified fields will get their default values, either ones defined in the record definition or the default default value `undefined`.

So if you want to give fields specific values then you must explicitly do this in the record, for example `#record_name{f1='$1',f2='$2',record_field=something}`. Often when using records and ets you want to set all the unspecified fields to `'_'`, the "don't care variable" for ets matching. There is a special syntax for this using the special, and otherwise illegal, field name `_`. For example `#record_name{record_field=something,_='_'}`.

Note that in your example you have set the the *record name element* in the tuple to '$1'. The tuple representing a record always has the record name as the first element. This means that when you create the ets table you should set the key position with `{keypos,Pos}` to something other than the default `1` otherwise there won't be any indexing and worse if you have a table of type 'set' or 'ordered_set' you will only get 1 element in the table. To get the index of a record field you can use the syntax `#Record.Field`, in your example `#record_name.record_field`.

Comment: After this example: `#record_name{f1='$1',f2='$2',record_field=something}` you gave the example: `#record_name{record_field=something,_='_'}.`  That makes it seem like writing `_='_'` once will match all the other fields--but in my attempts you have to write `_='_'` for each additional field.  That means if you change your record definition to have more or fewer fields, then you also have to change your match spec--which obviously is not ideal.  The one nice thing is: you don't have to specify the field you are matching, e.g. `record_field=something` , in the correct position in the tuple...

Comment: ...You can specify the field you are matching first, then follow that with the correct number of `_='_'`.  For instance with this record definition `-record(user, {id, name, city})`, you can use a pattern like this `#user{city="London", _='_', _='_'}`.

Answer (score 10):

Try using

```
ets:match(Table, #record_name{record_field=something, _='_'})
```

See [this](http://www.erlang.org/doc/programming_examples/records.html#id56878) for explanation.

Comment: In recent version OTP (24) ets:match/2 does not work this way, but ets:match_object/2 works fine.

Answer (score 4):

Format you are looking for is #record_name{record_field=something, _ = '_'}

http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#match-2

http://www.erlang.org/doc/programming_examples/records.html (see 1.3 Creating a record)